# Request Post URL is not working with Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I have tried requests.post in Django but it was not working. It was fine with request.get.

```
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
answer = requests.post('http://www.testing/getdata', data = {'testing': 'testing'}, verify=False,auth=(testing,testing),headers=headers)
```

Results:

```
"Unexpected Error Occurred:RESTEASY008200: JSON Binding deserialization error"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sent form data, but you set headers like you sent json.

I guess you wanna do something like that:

```py
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
answer = requests.post('http://www.testing/getdata', json = {'testing': 'testing'}, verify=False,auth=(testing,testing),headers=headers)
```

Comment: Thank you so much